# Is there a way in Postgres to generate a daily report skipping the weekends?

Tags: sql, postgresql

To be more specific,

I have a query that will run daily for reporting purposes. It uses data that was generated yesterday so the query looks like this

```
where sp.create_timestamp between (current_date -1 ) AND (current_date)
```

However, on Monday I would like to collect information for Friday instead of Sunday. Is there an easy way to ignore weekends.

If not I will have to write something in Python which I believe I can manage to do it there, but I couldn't find such function on SQL

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be solved by using `to_char()` with `'dy'` formatting pattern which will return 3 char of day in small letters

you can add condition like below:

```
where 
case when to_char(current_timestamp,'dy')='mon' then
sp.create_timestamp between (current_date -3 ) AND (current_date - 2)
else
sp.create_timestamp between (current_date -1 ) AND (current_date)
end
```

**EDIT**
Another way as per suggestion of @a_horse_with_no_name

```
where 
case when extract(isodow from current_timestamp) = 1 then
sp.create_timestamp between (current_date -3 ) AND (current_date - 2)
else
sp.create_timestamp between (current_date -1 ) AND (current_date)
end
```

you can add more conditions as required i.e. for Saturday or Sundays

Comment: It's better to not use language specific values. Use `extract(isodow from current_timestamp) = 1` instead - that will work regardless of the language of the current user.